# How to generate asdoc of Flex/AIR SDK it's self?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air, asdoc

How to use asdoc tools generate the api doc of Apache Flex SDK/Adobe AIR SDK it's self?
I need the offline flash actionscript 3.0 API doc with Apache Flex SDK doc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the flex sdk from the git repo, and run ant in the asdoc directory:
https://github.com/apache/flex-sdk/tree/develop/asdoc